# Append a struct inside a property which is an array inside other struct in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Hi All I need to append a struct inside an array which is a property of an other struct, I'm using Swift 3, however is not appending anything and I have no idea why, any help please?

```
import Foundation

struct Product {
    var objectId: String
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var qty: Int
    var img: String
    var desc: String
    var note: String
}

struct Order {
    var objectId: String
    var name: String
    var detail: [Product]
    mutating func addToDetail(_ product: Product) {
        detail.append(product)
    }
}

class OrderManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = OrderManager()

    var order: Order?

    var orderCreated: Bool {
        return self.order != nil
    }

    var partnerInOrder: String? {
        return self.order?.objectId
    }

    func createOrderIfNeeded(partnerId: String, name: String) {
        if self.order == nil {
            self.order = Order(objectId: partnerId, name: name, detail: [Product]())
        }

    }

    func addProduct(objectId: String, name: String, price: Double, qty: Int, img: String = "", desc: String = "", note: String = "") {
        guard var order = self.order else {
            return
        }

        let hasProduct = order.detail.contains(where: { $0.objectId == objectId })

        if !hasProduct {
            order.addToDetail(Product(objectId: objectId, name: name, price: price, qty: qty, img: img, desc: desc, note: note))
        }

        print("has product \(hasProduct)")
        print("the whole order is \(self.order)")
    }


    func addOption() {}

    func getProduct() {}

    func getOption() {}

    fileprivate func storeOrder() {}

}
```

Is getting inside the addToDetail func of the struct, but always my array is empty

Comment: yes, I even commented the if to call the function each time, but still is empty, weird!

Comment: can you put a break point inside the addToDetail method and see if the array is allocated or still nil ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following `guard` statement (in method `addProduct` of `OrderManager`)

```
guard var order = self.order else { /* ... */ }
```

you create a *copy* of `self.order` (given that it is not `nil`), due to the value semantics of structures in Swift. The subsequent call to `addToDetail` *on this copy* will not append a `Product` instance to the instance variable `order` of `self`, but only to the copy which goes out of scope as `addProduct` goes out of scope.

You could test this theory by replacing the optional binding clause in the `guard` statement above with a simple `nil` check (as @MartinR points out below, we don't really need a `guard` statement (after the fix: no binding), but can just perform an early `return` in case `self.order` is `nil`)

```
if self.order == nil { return }
```

Or, remove the explicit `nil` check altogether, and use optional chaining to decide whether or not to add a `product` to the `order` instance (combining the `nil` check and `hasProduct` in a single optional chaining clause):

```
func addProduct(objectId: String, name: String, price: Double, qty: Int, img: String = "", desc: String = "", note: String = "") {
    if !(self.order?.detail.contains(where: { $0.objectId == objectId }) ?? true) {
        order?.addToDetail(Product(objectId: objectId, name: name, price: price, qty: qty, img: img, desc: desc, note: note))
    }
    // ... remove the logging
}
```

This does a poorer job showing the intent of the code, though.

Comment: Yeah!!, you're good man, of course how I didn't see this, thanks! and the guard example, very nice, thanks again!!!

Comment: or `guard self.order != nil else {...}` which is the preferred way to check for a non-nil optional.

Comment: @Abizern That is also an (more common) alternative; I like using the pattern matching approach myself (although explicit check again `nil` might have more intent-showing semantics). Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Why not simply `if self.order == nil { return }` ?

Comment: @MartinR yes indeed, why not :D `guard` statement over-use blindness (by myself).

Comment: @goseta you might want to notice that the answer has had some changes and additions after valuable feedback from other SO members.